# Why use only one comparator for back-EMF (ESC build)

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, comparator, back-emf

I’m working on an esc project. I’ve got the motor spinning by just using a timer to switch the phases on and off. Now I’m trying to include circuitry for BEMF reading. I was watching a video from GreatScott who has a tutorial on creating an esc. For incorporating BEMF reading, he uses a comparator (which makes sense). However I am confused on one thing..

If you take a look at the schematic, there are 3 comparators. One for each phase:

[image]

However, on the actual circuit, he only uses 1 comparator:

[image]

Common sense tells me that all 3 phases could use the one comparator because there’s only one phase in which the BEMF would be read from at a time. Is my logic correct? Or is there another reason for this?

Comment: Might be muxing the one comparator around the phases, or assuming RPM difference is negligible between adjacent revolutions and doing an estimate of rotor position based on one position measurement per cycle and an RPM measurement.

Comment: The schematic does not show how or where these comparators are used. Be very careful of schematics taken from the web. I've come across a couple from great scott that were pretty awful.

Comment: Sorry that’s just a bad screenshot, he did show the full schematic, but I’ll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Ok so I do need 3 comparator ICs?

Answer (score 1):

The back-emf voltage is the output of a transducer that must be conditioned and then measured. The comparator is the measuring device. An analog switch will degrade the signal somewhat. This degradation must be compensated to get an accurate measurement. Charge injection during switching often appears in the analog channel.

So digital multiplexing is easier than analog multiplexing. There is (probably) no benefit in PCB real estate, or cost.

The measuring comparator can be placed very close to **each** signal source making a more accurate and robust measurement comparison. Each comparator output then has a position identity that is easier to transmit and process.

You would need 3 comparators.

Comment: Ok, thank you. What would be the method of digital multiplexing in this situation

Comment: Also, would I still need 3 comparators or just 1

Comment: @BigChungus443: The method of digital multiplexing depends on what you want to do with the signals. Perhaps ask another question.

Comment: Well it’s for the back emf reading for a bldc motor. Is this what you mean when you ask what am I trying to do with the signals?

Comment: @BigChungus443 Back EMF can be *measured* (analog) to measure the speed, or you can merely be detected/thresholded  (digital) to detect the passing pole for commutation, or it can merely be detected/thresholded to measure the time between pole passes to measure speed.